# Starting a session inside a class

Tags: php, class, session

It seems that starting the session inside a class method doesn't seem to work.

The simplest way would be to just start the session at the beginning of the script but doesn't it require overhead server resources to maintain if ran without usage ?

Seems more intuitive to start and run it only when user logs in. How can I do it inside class method?

It's a long line of code so i didn't include it first to not bother u. You should be considered only with 3rd if statement and userSession() method.

```
class Users extends Controller
{
   public function login(){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        //Sanitize input data
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $data = [
            'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
            'password' => trim($_POST['password']),
            'email_err' => '',
            'password_err' => ''
            ];

        if ($this->userModel->findUserByEmail($data['email'])) {
            //user found, Login
        if ($userRow = $this->userModel->login($data['email'], $data['password'])){
            $this->userSession($userRow);
            $this->view("pages/index");
        } elseif (!$this->userModel->login($data['email'], $data['password'])){
                $data['password_err'] = 'hujovas passwordas';
                $this->view("users/login", $data);
                }
        } else {
            //mail not found
            $data['email_err'] = 'email not found';
            $this->view('users/login', $data);
        }
    } else {
        //Sitas default
        $data = ['email' => '', 'password' => '', 'email_err' => '', 'password_err' => ''];
        $this->view("users/login", $data);
        }
}


public function userSession($userRow){

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userRow->ID;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $userRow->email;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $userRow->firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $userRow->lastname;
    redirect('pages/index');
}

}//class
```

Comment: where's this class you so famously talk of?

Comment: what's meant by `doesn't seem to work`

Comment: I call session_start(); inside a method of login class, which doesn't seem to register in any way. Public function userSession($userRow()){ session_start(); } doesn't work.

Comment: unfortunately, that's not enough to help. For all I know, you've placed it on the wrong line - I can't guess your code to help find the problem

Comment: What makes you think that something is not working? It should not matter where `session_start` is called **if** it is called

Comment: So you want to start a session only after user login. And how in another request you will know that user was logged in without starting that session first? What  I want to say is that your idea doesnt make any sense. Just start that session at the begining of script which is needed in your case

Comment: dear nospor, I was thinking about it(hen 2nd paragraph) but then i though that it might require extra resources to run the session unnecessarily every time the script starts, and only start it when needed(user logs in) but i guess that's not possible. I guess ill just start it at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you starting the session inside a class or stopping it working when done that way, but this issue is that the `session_start()` has to be run BEFORE any output is sent to the browser.

When you start the session in a class, there is no way of knowing if that class is going to be instantiated and the relevant method called BEFORE something else has passed something to the browser.

If you do

```
<?php
    $my_session = new session_class;

    .. code, code ,code
?>
<DOCTYPE html>
!<-- other html -->
```

Then it will probably work

But if you do

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    !<-- other html -->
<?php
$my_session = new session_class;
```

Then the session will definitely not work.

So when you try and start the session in some arbitrary class that is called at some arbitrary point in the HTML/PHP logic flow the likelyhood is that something somewhere will have already sent something to the browser. Basically you loose control.